# Outdoor load center

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, outdoor, pool

I'm planning to install a 8 space 16 cct outdoor load center for pool equipment. Does it have to be feed from a GFCI breaker in the house and if so does that mean I don't have to have any GFCI receptacles off that load center?

Thank you

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question, and take the [tour] so you know how to use this site.

Comment: Don't count on being able to use 16 circuits.  Most breakers these days need to be GFCI, AFCI or some other thing, and that means half sized breakers are not possible. If you need 16 circuits get a 16 space panel, but let me say nobody ever came in here going "Help! I need to add a circuit and there are plenty of breaker spaces because I got a nice big panel when I bought it!" Spaces are cheap.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, unless there is a local requirement, the subpanel does not need to fed from a GFCI breaker. In fact, that might lead to nuisance trips depending on the number of circuits and type of equipment fed from the subpanel, as cumulative small leaks can be enough to trip a GFCI. This is also a concern if you have a GFCI as the main breaker in the subpanel.

That being said, all your outdoor circuits, with the possible exception of overhead (and out of reach of anyone in the pool) lighting, needs to be GFCI protected. So you have 4 options:

- GFCI in main panel on subpanel feed
- GFCI main breaker in subpanel (this would also serve as a disconnect)
- GFCI on each individual circuit as a GFCI/breaker
- GFCI on each individual circuit as a GFCI/receptacle

Remember that generally speaking, GFCI breakers are full size. So if you use GFCI/breakers on individual circuits, you really only have 8 circuits to work with, not 16. That should be OK for a pool panel - e.g., pump x2, heater x2, lights x 1, receptacles x 1. Any hardwired loads must use GFCI/breaker since there is no receptacle - though if 120V you could use a deadfront GFCI but that really doesn't make sense here. And even for receptacles, there is an advantage to putting the GFCI in the subpanel as it should provide better protection from the weather than a weather-resistant GFCI receptacle.

A big advantage (thank you George) of using individual GFCI/breakers instead of a single GFCI/breaker to protect the entire subpanel is that if there is a trip at night caused, for example, the pool pump, the lights stay on.

Comment: We also need to remind the OP that this needs to be treated like a sub-panel, meaning don't bond the neutral to the ground and local ground rods must be installed.  It's going to be a 4 wire circuit (2 hots, a neutral and a ground).   IMHO, I'd use locally installed GFCI breakers not outlets bc they are outside and will suffer from weather.   If you went with the main feed breaker being GFCI, if it tripped, it'd shut down everything, pool pump, outlets, lights, etc. that are connected to the sub-panel

Comment: Ground rod only needed if a separate building. If the panel is on the outside wall of the same building that has the main panel, not needed.

Comment: Good point, manassehkatz, if it's on the same structure as the main building additional grounding isn't required.  I just made an assumption that it would be located near the pool equipment. It still needs to be treated as a sub-panel though.

Comment: Note that it's not really possible to have a subpanel with a GFCI main breaker due to the fact that GFCIs don't tolerate having power stuffed in their LOAD terminals very well